# Problems building a structured data classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have been trying to build a basic mock structured data classifier with only 1 sigmoid unit, so basically logistic regression I think. Everything has been working well until I get to training when the accuracy just stalls and stays the same.

```
X = np.array([[1,3],[2,4],[3,5]])
Y = np.array([1,0,1])
Y = Y.reshape(3,1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10)

Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 364ms/step - loss: 2.6870 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.6825 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.6780 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.6734 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.6689 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 2.6644 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.6599 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.6553 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 2.6508 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.6463 - accuracy: 0.3333
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model is not capable of fitting to your data
Your data looks something like this
[image: Data Plot]

It is not possible to fit a sigmoid curve to this data with more than 33.33% accuracy
This is why your model is not capable of achieving more than 33.33% accuracy
So, if you increase your model size, you will achieve a higher accuracy with your model

Comment: Yes but wouldn't the still accuracy bounce around a bit and would not be able to hit the local minimum first epoch ?

Comment: Actually, 33.33% is not the maximum accuracy achieved. Try training the model for more epochs (maybe 200-300) and you will see that the accuracy does jump to 66.66%.